# Accidentally deleted .git/objects folder

Tags: git

I Accidentally deleted .git/objects folder. I have had commits that haven't been pushed to the remote yet so i'm worried that some changes are lost.
*What can i do now to restore them?*

Comment: The commits are lost. Make a backup of your working tree so that you at least have the latest state of all your files

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot restore the folder like C1sc0 suggested, a fairly simple solution would be to just clone the git project into a new directory, then compare the folder where you deleted the .git folder with the folder you just cloned the git project inside. Some IDEs have a very good compare function that makes this quite easy. Then just paste the changes over, commit and push. After you are sure everything works, you can delete the folder where you deleted the .git folder from, as the new one should have all your changes.

Answer (score 1):

If it has been *deleted*, like for real..... not much git can do here. You will need to do some work to be able to resume work, but forget about the revisions you had created locally. So... clone a *second* repo from the original repo that you started working from (assuming you are working as people normally do these days using a central repo to work against).

When you have that, create a branch (what will be *your branch* from now on) on the latest revision that you were able to merge from the upstream branch in the original repo (assuming it's not the tip of the upstream branch.... but it *could* be the tip).... *or*, if you never merged, then set the branch at the same commit where your branch was started from.

Checkout that branch and now replace the working tree with what you have in the working tree of the *broken* repo (do not bring anything from git's database).... now you can resume working on that branch.

By the way, I am making a bunch of assumptions:

- You had a single branch laying around with changes that had not been pushed into the remote. If you had more branched that had not been pushed, you are out of luck because you won't be able to get the back from the broken repo.
- You were working against a single branch while you were developing. If you had been, say, cherry-picking stuff from a different branch than your upstream, then it needs *more work* to be able to be in a *resumable* state.

And there could be others that my *subconscious* me is hiding from me to make my life simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you can restore it from the recycle bin. (And similarly on linux from Trash) (except if you deleted with shift+delete)

Comment: I'm on linux, and they've been deleted properly, so i do not have them in bin :/

Comment: Then unfortunately you have to recreate your commits :( (the working directory is still intact, for security reasons clone the repository to another location, overwrite the new working directory with the old one and recreate your commits .